# How to force Oasis to build the documentation in a given directory?

Tags: ocaml, oasis

I am using the [Oasis](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/) build system for an OCaml projects and I would like to build the documentation and to get it in `${projectroot}/doc/api/`.

For now, my `_oasis` file is something like that:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name: MyProject
Version: 0.1alpha
Plugins: META (0.4)
BuildTools: ocamlbuild
AlphaFeatures: ocamlbuild_more_args

PostDistcleanCommand: $rm _tags myocamlbuild.ml setup.ml setup.data

Document api
Title: MyProject API
Type: ocamlbuild (0.4)
BuildTools: ocamldoc
XOCamlbuildPath: src
XOCamlbuildExtraArgs: -docflags -d,doc/api,-colorize-code,-charset,utf-8
```

Then, I run the following commands:

```
$> oasis setup
$> ocaml setup.ml -configure
...
$> ocaml setup.ml -doc
...
```

Then, I get a link `api.docdir/ --> _build/src/api.docdir/` at the top directory of the project linking to the documentation that I expect. But, it seems that the `-d doc/api` with the extra-arguments has not been taken into account.

So, what did I miss ? Because, I am a bit running out of ideas here...

Comment: I suspect you can't do what you want. oasis uses ocamlbuild and this is [the way](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamlbuild.html#sec405) ocamldoc generation works with ocamlbuild. If you write your api.odocl file in doc then the documentation will be in doc/api.docdir but I don't know if you can do this with oasis.

Comment: Having `doc/api.docdir` would be also fine for me. It is more about the fact to have everything at the project rootdir that disturb me. But, as I am quite new to OCaml, if having the link at the topdir is the usual way to do, I will conform to it. I'm just learning.

Comment: The symlink is just a convenience you can avoid it by invoking ocamlbuild with `--no-links`.

Comment: Beware, the option is `-no-links` (a unique dash at start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way would be to use `install` command that will copy your documentation (as well as other data) to a proper place, that is customizable with `configure` command, or with `InstallDir` field.

Also, if you still want to migrate your documentation inside your project, without doing the installation, then you can use `PostCommand` field, and use a small script (or just a one-liner) to move your documentation in a better place.

Comment: I guess that this is the way to do it. I am not really found of having a `PostCommand` but if it does the job, it's okay for me. Now, I better understand why you had this `bapdoc.ml` in BAP. :-)

Comment: the main reason, is that `ocamldoc` behaves incorrectly in the presence of camlp4 syntax extensions. So this script just performs preprocessing to remove preprocessing :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that comment because I am not yet using camlp4 and that might help in the future !

Comment: `install` and `configure` commands for what program, used how?